# Twilio : sender does not support reply. allowed domestic only. how make it reply able from any number?

Tags: twilio

I have Trial account of Twilio. When I send a SMS it does not support reply but I want the receiver to be able to reply as well. In Twilio console I can see that it supports receive SMS from domestic number only. How can make it possible to receive from any number. Thats possible in Trial account right? Or can I change the region for now to test replies from other numbers? I am using a simple node js code to send SMS.

```
  function sendSMS(from, to, body) {
 

  client.messages.create(
    {
      to, // Recipient's number
      messagingServiceSid: TWILIO_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID, // Twilio Messaging SID
      body, // Message to Recipient
    },
    (error, message) => {
      if (error) {
        fail(error);
      } else {
        //success({ to, body });
        console.log('message sent');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: You can receive messages sent to your Twilio numbers, including while on trial account. Your situation likely depends on where in the world you are and what country number you bought. Can you share that with me?

Comment: The number is of United States and I am from Nepal . Is there a way for me to be able test the reply feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We provide guidelines for how messaging is supported in different countries, you can read the [SMS guidelines for Nepal here](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/np/sms).

Twilio does not support domestic numbers in Nepal, so you can only send messages to Nepal from an international number, like the US number you currently have. However, normally due to country level restrictions, when you send a message from an international number the sender ID is not preserved. That is, the message will appear to come from a different number/short code/alphanumeric ID than the one you sent it from. For this reason, if a user tries to reply to that message the message may fail to send or just won't be directed back to Twilio.

If you, or your user, takes your US number and sends an SMS message directly to it, you will receive that though.